# Disable JavaScript keypress events in iframes

Tags: javascript, events

How do I disable the support for JavaScript keypress events in iframes?

I need keypress events disabled only in specific iframes, so doing a catch-all-events-and-make-em-do-nothing solution is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this [example](http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/200503/test2005031201.html) does what you want ?

According to this [thread](http://bytes.com/groups/javascript/151221-capturing-keypress-designmode-iframe-possible), something along the line of:

```
document.getElementById('edit').contentWindow.addEventListener('keypress', cK, true);
```

helps capturing keypress in a given iframe. If they can be captured, they can be disabled.

Warning: as pointed out by [Allain Lalonde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443/allain-lalonde) in the comments:

> This will work if the iframe's content isn't from another domain.

Comment: This will work if the iframe's content isn't from another domain.  Thought that might be relevant.