# Restricting enter keypress event in an IFrame, does not work

Tags: javascript, iframe, keypress, designmode, richtextediting

I have an IFrame within my page and am using the designMode="on" on this iframe for a small-level rich text editing.

My concern is that I need not allow the user to enter new lines in it - meaning, I want to restrict enter keys.

I did it using the [question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328887/disable-javascript-keypress-events-in-iframes) to listen to the keypress events. But in my keypress event, if I **return false**, nothing happens.

How do I restrict enter keys in Iframe with designmode?

Code :

```
      document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.addEventListener('keypress',restrictEnterKey, true);

            function restrictEnterKey(event) {
                var key=(event.charCode)?event.charCode:((event.keyCode)?event.keyCode:((event.which)?event.which:0));
                if (key == 13) {
                    //alert('me');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `preventDefault` on the event or set `returnValue` to `false` for IE. The following function will do the job:

```
function preventDefault(evt) {
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (typeof evt.returnValue !== "undefined") {
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```